# Lodash: order array of objects by boolean?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects I'd like to order (essentially it's a table):

```
myArr = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    accepted: true
}, {
    name: 'Alfred',
    email: 'alfred@gmail.com',
    accepted: false
}]
```

I'm using orderBy from lodash like so:

```
//get columnName to sort by from another function
const newArr = _.orderBy(myArr, [columnName], ['asc'])
```

Ordering by name and email works fine, for accepted it doesn't do anything though. I understand I can store accepted as 0 and 1, but is there another way? Is lodash sufficient for that, or should I create a separate function for this?

Comment: It works fine - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kksgmph6/)

Comment: Stupid me! There is something with my view layer then...

Comment: Enjoy the view :)

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this question: be aware that because you're sorting a boolean, you're actually sorting **0** or **1**. If you'd like the objects with **'true'** to be on top, you should specify that it should sort **desc** (0/false is going to be on top otherwise).

Comment: @Erwin Lengkeek - i tried with 3 boolean fields - doesnt work - i think lodash cannot handle this situtaion :(

Answer (score 6):

You can try this in **ES6** Notation

```
const newArr = [
    ...myArr.filter(c => c.accepted === false),
    ...myArr.filter(c => c.accepted === true)
];
```

You can also use **Array.sort Prototype**

```
myArr.sort((a, b) => (a.accepted - b.accepted));
```

Comment: Can you explain what ES6 notation code does in your answer please ?

Comment: In ES6 notation we are creating a new array by concatenating 2 arrays. The first array has items filtered by accepted === false and the other array has items filtered by accepted === true. This will insert the accepted items in the last of the newly created array.

Answer (score 1):

@Erwin Lengkeek that worked for me, by sorting my `booleanField` descending, the Trues were on top.

```
this.sortableList = orderBy(this.sortableList, ['booleanField', 'stringField'], ['desc', 'asc']);
```